# Validation checks on dataset ADF vs databricks

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I want to perform some file level, field level validation checks on the dataset I receive.

Given below some checks which I want to perform and capture any issues into audit tables.

- File Level Checks: File present, size of the file, Count of records matches to count present in control file
- Field Level checks: Content in right format, Duplicate key checks, range in important fields.

I want to make this as a template so that all the project can adopt it, Is it good to perform these checks in ADF or in Databricks. If it is ADF any reference to example dataflow/pipeline would be very helpful.

Thanks,
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish these tasks by using various Activities in Azure data factory pipeline.

To check the file existence, you can use [Validation Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-validation-activity).

In the validation activity, you specify several things. The `dataset` you want to validate the existence of, `sleep` how long you want to wait between retries, and `timeout` how long it should try before giving up and timing out. The `minimum size` is optional.

Be sure to set the timeout value properly. The default is 7 days, much too long for most jobs.

If the file is found, the activity reports success.
If the file is not found, or is smaller than minimum size, then it can timeout, which is treated like a failure by dependencies.

To count of matching records and assuming that you are using CSV, you could create a generic dataset (one column) and run a copy activity over whatever folders you want to count to a temp folder. Get the rowcount of the copy activity and save it.
At the end, delete everything in your temp folder.

Something like this:

Lookup Activity (Get's your list of base folders - Just for easy rerunning)

For Each (Base Folder)

Copy Recursively to temp folder

Stored procedure activity which stores the Copy Activity.output.rowsCopied

Delete temp files recursively.

To use the same pipeline repeatedly for multiple datasets, you can make your pipeline dynamic. Refer: https://sqlitybi.com/how-to-build-dynamic-azure-data-factory-pipelines/